# NGXS | Dispatch or Select called multiple times

Tags: angular, ngxs

I am using NGXS for my application and I'm new to this. I have seen some of the dispatch actions are called multiple times. I checked in the console and there are multiple calls to the API.

I thought it's to do with subscribing the actions and I removed the subscribe code but it doesn't change anything.

Below is the app.component.ts file. I have three dropdowns to select country, state and city. Based on selection of city, it navigates to city details page.

SetStates and SetCities are actions which calls API and FetchCityDetails is also an action which calls an API.

I have noticed that api's for first two methods i.e. SetStates and SetCities are called only once but FetchCityDetails is called two times i.e. calling the api two times in console.

What could be the reason?

```
// called on country dropdown selection change
  selectCountry(event) {
      this.store.dispatch([
        new SetCountry(event.value),
        new SetStates(event.value),
        new SetCities(''),
      ]);
  }

// called on state dropdown selection change
  selectState(event) {
    this.store.dispatch([
      new SetState(event.value),
      new SetCities(event.value)
    ]);
  this.state = event.value;
  }

// called on city dropdown selection change
  selectCity(event) {
    this.store.dispatch(new FetchCityDetails(this.state, event.value));
    this._route.navigate(['cityDetails']);
  }
```

NOTE: I just noticed that multiple calls are happening when I route from one page to another. The subscribe gets executed twice.

Comment: You're changing the route in the selectCity method.  Does the new route call dispatch FetchCityDetails?

Comment: No, this is the only time I call this action.

Comment: I have a selector in new route and display the details using async pipe (in the routed component) but I don't call this method again.